# code works on JSFiddle but not in local file

Tags: jquery, jsp

I found a simple JQuery code on JSFiddle but when I tried it in my eclipse it does not do what it supposed to do. I had checked it for many times still cannot find the reason why it is not working properly. any ideas?

HTMl

```
<textarea id="txt" rows="15" cols="70">There is some text here.</textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="OK" />
```

JQuery

```
jQuery("#btn").on('click', function() {
    var caretPos = document.getElementById("txt").selectionStart;
    var textAreaTxt = jQuery("#txt").val();
    var txtToAdd = "stuff";
    jQuery("#txt").val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );
});
```

**[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/NaHTw/4/)**

Comment: Have u imported necessary jQuery files?(Which is not necessary to import in jsfiddle)

Comment: You should wrap the code in dom ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three things need to be pay attention:

1. Must load jQuery on your page. Like this:

2. the jQuery lib position must load before your script.
3. your code must be wrapped used $(function (){}), or your code load after the DOM loaded.

Comment: oh thanks, I did not notice that function must wrapped with $(function (){})

Answer (score 0):

Often when testing locally, there is a problem because javascript is not executed when you just open the file in the browser.

Do you have a local webserver setup like wamp/mamp/xampp? If you access your file that way it should work.

I don't know if eclipse has a webserver built in, like for example NetBeans does.

To further get to the root of the problem, you should enable the console to see if any errors are output.

In Chrome press CTRL+SHIFT+J and reload the page.